# CSS styles not working in <td>

Tags: html, css

i am fetching data from DB to a `table` and i am trying to apply some CSS to the data fetched , but CSS like `pre-wrap` and other formatting options are not working

jsp code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<td class="tdx" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" id="sol" style="background-color:white;border-style:ridge">

         <div class="dialog" style="display: none;">

                <p id="dbox" style="white-space: pre-wrap;text-align:left"><%=solution%></p>

         </div>

  </td>
```

**NOTE** data in DB is properly formatted and `text-align:left` is working

Comment: Instead of white-space use `word-break:break-all`

Comment: @GermanoPlebani its not working

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ — Your HTML is invalid. I question the relevance of the jQuery code. Your sample data appears to be an ASP tag so isn't HTML or long enough to wrap anyway.

Comment: its jsp code and yes the data in <td> is long , very long

Comment: @amolsingh — So provide enough of it to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: i got the ans finally ... issue was with CSS rendering in IE ... this helped 
` <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some tags like (table and tr) :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdx" id="sol" style="background-color:red;border-style:ridge">

      <div class="dialog" style="display: block;">

        <p id="dbox" style="white-space: pre-wrap;text-align:left">test</p>

      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope that helps.